# I have no idea what this is saying. Can you have two topics in a sentence?

Tags: particle-に, syntax, particle-は

白い箱はカウチの上に緑のランプは机の上にあります。

This sentence looks like it has two topics in it. But when I try to translate it, it doesn't make sense (to me obviously). My direct translation is: `A white box on top of the couch a green lamp is on top of the desk.` Obviously, that's not gonna work. To me, it's like the first phrase is missing a verb. What am I missing?

Comment: Is there a comma missing in there, like 白はkはカウチの上に、緑の～? I believe generally you'd need a verb after that 上に, like 上にあって or 上にあり, but it looks like it's just saying where each of those two things is with a single verb.

Comment: @ssb It's a straight copy. I've made no alterations.

Comment: I think the two part are sharing a verb.

Comment: A straight copy from where? From something that might be a bit loose on punctuation?

Comment: @fefe Is that normal?

Comment: @dotnetN00b Well, I don't know ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As ssb and fefe wrote, the sentence consists of two clauses which share the main verb あります.  In this particular case, it would be easier to read if the author put a 読点 (“、”) in the sentence:

> 白い箱はカウチの上に、緑のランプは机の上にあります。

However, unlike commas in English, 読点 in Japanese is rarely <del>(if ever)</del> grammatically required.  Authors are free to use 読点 wherever they feel that it makes sense to make a pause when pronounced.  (But see [this post by snailplane](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9764/%e3%80%8c%e3%81%93%e3%82%8f%e3%81%84%e3%81%a0%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%80%82%e3%80%8d-versus-%e3%80%8c%e3%81%93%e3%82%8f%e3%81%84%e3%80%81%e3%81%a0%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89-%e3%80%8d) for an example where omitting 読点 would make a sentence ungrammatical.)

Comment: The lack of strict rules for 読点 make it rather difficult for foreigners to understand at times. Thanks for clearing this up.